# How to set the environment in a Symfony2 console command

Tags: symfony

Hopefully a simple question - how does one specify which environment to use when running a console command in Symfony2. I've created a few commands, however I would like to run them in the context of my 'staging' environment when on my staging server and my 'prod' environment when on my production server (the different environments define different database connections). How do I configure and pass this information to my console command?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have two options that will help you out. You can specify the environment that the console will run in with the `--env` flag, and use `--no-debug` to disable debug mode.

`php app/console --env=staging your:console:command` or `php app/console --env=prod your:console:command` should do what you're looking for (the console runs in the `dev` environment with debug on by default).

You can look at the code of the `app/console` file for more info.

Answer (score 54):

You can also use the SYMFONY_ENV environment variable to set a default environment distinct to 'dev' (e.g. `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod` in `~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: For Symfony 4 use `APP_ENV` instead

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question @croca had, to expand on what @Francesc Rosàs posted, and as @Problematic suggested.

If you look in app/console you should see `$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');`

All this does is checks the input arguments passed to the console for `--env` or `-e`, checks the default value from `getenv('SYMFONY_ENV')`, or sets it to `dev` if neither are supplied.

It is then passed to `$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);`

You could essentially either make changes directly to app/console to achieve your application's specific functionality or copy app/console to a separate file such as app/exec, then process the $env variable how you prefer to determine the desired environment.

**Simple Example:** app/exec

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
 /**
  * disabled debug mode, 
  * set environment based on requesting address being local 
  * otherwise the server's IP address
  * be sure to perform at least chmod(750) on the file to ensure it is executable
  * otherwise it must be prefixed with your php executable
  */     

set_time_limit(0);

require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '::1' ? 'dev' :
    ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] === '192.168.2.1' ? 'test' : 'prod')
);
$kernel = new AppKernel($env, false);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

Then call `php app/exec namespace:command arguments --flags`

Additionally you could process your own application instead of using the app/console AppKernel - instructions from Symfony can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

Answer (score 5):

The official documentation says:

> By default, console commands run in the dev environment and you may want to change this for some commands.

So, as @Problematic suggest, you can specify the environment for your command using the flag "--env=*your_env*" or its shortcut "-e *your_env*".

I wonder whether it is possible to force the default environment for a command. I mean, without having to use the flags. Any idea?

Comment: For setting the default environment without using a flag, set the `SYMFONY_ENV` environment variable - see [Francesc Rosàs's answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571729/328817).

Answer (score 5):

There is another variant, not so convenient though, but works also with `composer`

```
SYMFONY_ENV=prod app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look at the implementation of the cache:clear command. This may give you some clues on how to choose the environment from a command.

```
app/console help cache:clear
```