# PHP: Symfony2 web application's URL

Tags: php, url, symfony, web, uri

So I have this question: I have a web application on xampp. 
Now my URL is: `localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/inbox`
But I want it to be just `localhost/inbox` for example.
Is that possible? I only know the way to do it with nginx, but not with the xampp or symfony routing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669458/how-to-remove-web-app-dev-php-from-symfony2-urls?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you have do edit the `.htaccess`

you can use this one and put in on `localhost/symfony/web`:

```
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_dev\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app_dev.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**PS:** your URL will be `localhost/symfony/inbox` as it should be. Then when you'll put it on a server, you'll put all the files in the root and your URL will be `domain.com/inbox`

hope this helps :)

Comment: Now my URL is localhost/symfony/web/inbox, how can I fix it to drop that /web?

Comment: try to edit `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]` with `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/web/app_dev.php [L]`

Comment: and put the `.htaccess` on `localhost/symfony` not `localhost/symfony/web`

Comment: I can't do that, I get error. htaccess has to be in web folder.

Error: `An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).
Do you want to open the profiler?`

Comment: mh, i don't know that suggest you then, you have to try a little bit.. note that you'll have also to switch to `prod` envroinment that will access to `app.php` not `app_dev.php` and when you'll put the project online you will probably work with linux, so you'll have do to it again on your server in which you can set `DocumentRoot /var/www/Symfony/web`. After that, this `.htaccess` will work fine. Consider what to do then, if you really need this to be working in local environment

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Apache config file to point `DocumentRoot` correctly to `web` folder:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/Symfony/web
<Directory /var/www/Symfony/web>
    ... something goes here ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: then it still would be `domain.com/app.php/inbox` ;)

Comment: @ponciste it depends what is placed instead of `... something goes here ...` in the config ;)

Comment: But if I'm working on few projects on my xampp server it might get uncomfortable. Btw later I'm planning to upload this code online, so there won;t be any apache configs.